# Spring Controllers and Threading

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I have one question regarding controllers.

I have a controller which will be used to edit some data in a database, if it is accessed by multiple users at the same time by unknowingly..then I hope it will store wrong data in database, is it possible to make it controlled by threading..if possible can any one please help me how to that.

Thanks in Advance,

Regards,
Raja.

Comment: aren't your services transactional? or what exactly do you mean with "store wrong data in database"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to use it for multiple users at the same time by unknowingly
you have to make that services as transaction

```
    <bean id="txManager"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

 <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
```

Spring will handle all of your transactions.
And I think wrong data means in-consistence data.. Yes this transactions roll backs to previous state if you try to insert wrong data.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html